# CSOM Search API does not return all the results

Tags: javascript, search, jquery, csom, search-api

I am having a problem with the code below. It is not returning all the rows/items which are found in different lists. The total number of items is 28, but the code below is returning 19. I have set the `rowlimit` to different values and the funny thing is that when I set it to 10, it returns me 23 results back. But when I set it to 50, for example, I get 19. What is going on?

On the same page I am using content search web part, and that returns 28 results. The content type that I am using is the same as in Content Search web part. You might ask why don't I use Content Search web part, and the answer is that I cannot use it because the customer has got SharePoint standard edition.

```
var queryText = "ContentTypeId:0x010066FA3DE3E334C841B418C82CC475A227*";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://dev");
var contextSite = clientContext.get_site();
var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext); 
keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryText); 
keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);

var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);  
var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);

function onQuerySuccess()
{
    var message = $("#message");
    message.text("Search results fro \"" + queryText + "\"");
    message.append("<br />");
    var rows = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;
    $.each(rows, function(index, value)
    {
        message.append(value.Title + ": " + value.Path);
        message.append("<br />");
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried to set `keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/DE-DE/library/jj916953.aspx)) because maybe some rows / items are incorrectly treated as duplicates by search?

Comment: Thanks man! You made my day. It worked. It returned all 28 results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was a great question and good that you added your code as well. 
In my case I was trying to get all the site collection inside Content Search  display template 
 I was not getting all the result but by adding `"keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);"`

I started to get all the results. Below is the code that worked for me. By the way deffered approach doesnt make it synchronous and I dont own this code either.

```
function RetrieveWebSiteUsingSearch(siteUrl,groupElm)
            {

                var d = $.Deferred();
                SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () 
                {
                    SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Search.js", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery", function () 
                    {
                        var sContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                        var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(sContext);
                        keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
                        keywordQuery.set_queryText("contentclass:sts_site");
                        keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);
                        var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(sContext);
                        results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
                        sContext.executeQueryAsync(
                            function () 
                            {
                                var sitePath = '';
                                var siteTitle = '';
                                for (var i= 0; i < results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows.length; i++) 
                                { 
                                    sitePath = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[i].Path;
                                    siteTitle = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[i].Title;
                                    dictUrlTitlePairs["'"+sitePath+"'"] = siteTitle;
                                    //alert(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows[i].ContentType) 
                                }   
                                search.Grouping.show(groupElm);
                                d.resolve(results);

                            },
                            function (err) 
                            {
                                d.reject(null);
                            }
                            );
                    });
                });

                return d.promise();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below are the code for searching in specific library with all result

```
 using (clientContext = new ClientContext(siteName))
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                clientContext.Credentials = GetSharePointNetworkCredential();
                KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);


                 clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName.Replace("%20", " "));
                keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;
                keywordQuery.QueryText = String.Format("{0} AND Path:\"{1}\"", "*searchkeyword*", "SiteName");
                SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
                searchExecutor.RefreshLoad();

                ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

               
                foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} ({2})", resultRow["Title"], resultRow["Path"], resultRow["Write"]);
                }
}
```