# How to display Search API results like SharePoint OOTB list with filtering, sorting, paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom, search-api

I would like to display Search API results like OOTB Sharepoint list with filtering at least. Is it possible to use SharePoint javascript libraries to achieve this? If not, is there any jquery/javascript library which might help display results in table form?

I am using code from my previous post: [CSOM Search API does not return all the results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154206/csom-search-api-does-not-return-all-the-results?noredirect=1#comment158163_154206)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could display your results using datatables. Although not looking exactly like Sharepoint, it should give you the features you are looking for - filtering, sorting, paging.

[DataTables Table plug-in for jQuery](https://www.datatables.net/)